# Are MonoDroid (Xamarin) apps less prone to theft?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I've been investigating Google Play License Verification Library to decrease piracy of an app I am finishing up. But it seems rather easy to to crack apps that use LVL (see [How the Android License Verification Library is Lulling You into a False Sense of Security](http://www.digipom.com/how-the-android-license-verification-library-is-lulling-you-into-a-false-sense-of-security/).

My question is, are MonoDroid apps inherently less crackable in this area? The attack points seem to be the user code that handles the logic of performing the check, handling result, storing result, etc. Automated tools look for common Java code patterns. I would think these would be worthless with MonoDroid app, since the C# code is not converted to Java bytecode, but is instead stored as standard .NET IL that gets JITd at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, are MonoDroid apps inherently less crackable in this area?

No. Xamarin.Android just alters things; it doesn't change the problem domain in any significant fashion.

> Automated tools look for common Java code patterns.

Nothing prevents automated tools from looking for common .NET code patterns, meaning nothing will give Xamarin.Android code a definite long-term advantage. There may be a short-term advantage, in that tooling won't know what to do with it *now*.

That said, we are looking into ways of further obfuscating IL. The forthcoming 4.8 release will have [mkbundle support](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=man%3amkbundle%281%29), which will make it more difficult to find the IL within the `.apk`. However, this is just an added form of obfuscation, and will doubtless be cracked in time, just as most forms of DRM are cracked in time.

There is no silver bullet.

Comment: Maybe I should have asked "are they less crackacble TODAY." I does sound like today there is an advantage as I don't believe any script kiddy style tools support the IL part. And you from there they would have to know both Java and .NET to do a crack. So a big barrier today. And given a small number of Xamarin apps compared to Java, less incentive to do the work.